# sorting algorithms using stack in java

Tags: java

I'm trying to sort elements using stack. I do everything but I did not git the output sorted..
My Code:

```
    Scanner oman= new Scanner(System.in);


    System.out.println(" Enter the size of stack: ");
    int stackSize = oman.nextInt();


    Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<Integer>();
    for(int i = 0; i < stackSize; i++){

        System.out.println("Enter the number : ");
        int number = oman.nextInt();

         System.out.println("The Number is entered in the stack. ");
         stack.push(number);
    }

    while (!(stack.isEmpty())) {
        System.out.println(stack.pop());

    }
```

Example:

```
Input

Enter the size of stack: 3
Enter the First Number :10
Enter the Second Number : 5
Enter The T hired Number : 20 

Output

3
5
10
20
```

like this

Comment: You haven't attempted to sort anything...

Comment: Why do you need stack to sort elements?

Comment: A stack is a data structure. It's meant to store data not sort it.

Comment: From a theoretical view: How could a `Stack` help here?

Comment: My Assignment question is this: Write and execute JAVA program to create an object of the  class which accepts
numbers from keyboard to be inserted using prior stack( has values increasing order)

Answer (score 0):

Hint: You need 2 stacks.

- The first stack contains the elements in their correct order
- The second stack contains elements in the reverse order ... temporarily ... while you find the correct place to push them onto the first stack.

Hint 2:  Here's a puzzle:

1. Cut up a sheet of card into N cards.  Write the numbers 1 to N on the cards.
2. Shuffle the cards.  Place them in a pile called `I` (for input).
3. Using two extra piles called `S` (for sorted) and `T` (for temporary), move all cards from `I` to `S` with the following constraints:

   - You can only move a card from the top of one pile to the top of another.
   - You cannot move a card onto the `I` pile.
   - When you are finished, pile `S` must contain all of the cards in the order 1 ... to N.

If you can solve this puzzle, you have developed an *algorithm* for sorting using stacks.

Answer (score -1):

Where is the code for sorting? I suggest you compare the elements before pushing them into the stack. You push the elements only when they are bigger than the top element in the stack. (i.e 10 is on the top of the stack. Next is 5. Now you compare 5 and 10. 10 is bigger, so pop it out and push 5. Then push 10. Next is 20. it is bigger than 10 so you push it)

Comment: 1) What you're suggesting doesn't work so easily, as you cannot just compare elements before pushing - you'd have to pop element by element to find insertion point, including the top element, which you would not know the value of unless you either popped it or had it cached in code. 2) What you posted isn't an answer - it's a general idea on how someone might go about this. The OP's question is just a requirement, and as written, off-topic as "too broad."